# Add extra control to rigify?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, rigify

I am using rigify and it works great, but I also want to add an empty sphere, that will allow me move part of the clothe, for example on this photo:

[image]

But I also want when I create the extra bone from rigify, to apply it to the clothe as control without breaking the already applied skin weight. Can someone guide me on how to do this? I need this controller so I can move the area of the clothe that is behind the middle area of the legs to push the clothe closer towards the legs, as the character sits on a chair for example, so the clothe won't go through the chair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, in this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtX_zBVwBgI&t=973s